# I am getting exception while launching the App Action Test Tool

Tags: android, deep-linking, google-assistant-sdk, app-actions

I am trying to test the actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE from build in intents but I am getting error while launching the App Action Test Tool for build in intents, It was working fine a couple of hours before I get that error.

Following is the error when I try to launch the App Actions

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property onlineDevicesStateSubject has not been initialized
    at com.google.assistant.plugin.PluginSingletons$Companion.getOnlineDevicesStateSubject(PluginSingletons.kt:9)
    at com.google.assistant.plugin.ui.ActionSelectionDialog.createPreviewTestingFrame(ActionSelectionDialog.kt:353)
    at com.google.assistant.plugin.ui.ActionSelectionDialog.createCenterPanel(ActionSelectionDialog.kt:136)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.init(DialogWrapper.java:1331)
    at com.google.assistant.plugin.ui.ActionSelectionDialog.<init>(ActionSelectionDialog.kt:106)
    at com.google.assistant.plugin.actions.ActionsTestAction.actionPerformed(ActionsTestAction.kt:21)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:281)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:310)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:286)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:77)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:299)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:110)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:95)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:110)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:514)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:544)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6652)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3345)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6417)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5027)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4859)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2784)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4859)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:976)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:911)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:840)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:454)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:773)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:453)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:828)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:507)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Following is the code I am using in my actions file

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?><!--  Learn More about how to use App Actions: https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/index.html -->
<actions>
    <action intentName="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
        <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://url.page.link/open{?featureName}">
            <parameter-mapping
                intentParameter="feature"
                urlParameter="featureName" />
        </fulfillment>

        <parameter name="feature">
            <entity-set-reference entitySetId="FeatureEntitySet" />
        </parameter>
    </action>

    <entity-set entitySetId="FeatureEntitySet">
        <entity
            name="Profile"
            identifier="profile" />
        <entity
            name="Setting"
            identifier="setting" />
        <entity
            name="Gang"
            identifier="gang" />
        <entity
            name="Blind"
            identifier="blind" />
        <entity
            name="Light"
            identifier="light" />
    </entity-set>
</actions>
```

And for Manifest I add the following in the application tag

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.actions"
    android:resource="@xml/actions" />
```

And for the Activity I add the following intent

```
intent-filter
    android:autoVerify="true"
    tools:targetApi="m">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="url.page.link"
        android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

And in activity I add the following to take actions against the intent

```
intent.handleIntent()

private fun Intent.handleIntent() {
    when (action) {
        Intent.ACTION_VIEW -> {
            handleDeepLink(data)
        }
    }
}

private fun handleDeepLink(data: Uri?) {
    if (data?.path == "/open") {
        featureType = data.getQueryParameter("featureName").orEmpty()
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Working $featureType", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be posted as a bug report for the test tool.  It's not something Stack Overflow can address, since the problem is not with code you've written.  Please file the bug and provide as much information as you have, especially the steps that anyone can take to reproduce the issue.  Be sure to include information about your machine and Android Studio.  https://buganizer.corp.google.com/issues?q=componentid:617864

Comment: yes @DougStevenson I have created a bug on that side as well, here is the link
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199925662